# HTML5 video flash fallback. Being able to control the video

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, html

I have a HTML5 video with jquery hooking into the player like so:
`video.currentTime += 1;`
But when IE comes along and insists on using Flash plugins, none of my JQ will work - How am i supposed to control the video when Flash takes over from HTML5?

The player im falling back to is JQplayer as "player.swf"

Comment: You need to have two code paths 1) using native <video> API 2) Using JQplayer exposed Javascript APIs (if supported) At least Flowplayer can support timing callbacks.

Comment: Try VideoJS instead. http://videojs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - you can't, unless the player itself provides an interface that you can hook into. One of the reasons why Flash video is a pain.